# Rspec cannot check logger info output

Tags: ruby, logging, rspec

I have an non-rails ruby application, that uses logger to handle log output to stdout.
I want to add specs for checking that output and found two ways to implement this and seems both ways don't work.

So both ways are in this spec.rb file:

```
require 'rspec' 
require 'logger'

describe 'Logger' do   
  it 'expect to output' do
    expect { Logger.new(STDOUT).info('Hello') }.to output.to_stdout    
  end

  it 'expect to recieve' do
    expect(Logger.new(STDOUT).info('Hello')).to receive(:info)   
  end 
end
```

I have output to terminal with log messages, but both verification are failed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace `STDOUT` with `$stdout`. This works:

```rb
expect { Logger.new($stdout).info('Hello') }.to output.to_stdout
```

The reason is that Rspec internally modifies the global variable `$stdout` to capture its contents with an `StringIO`. When using the constant, this mechanism does not work because `STDOUT` keeps the original value of `$stdout`.

Notice that you will have a similar problem is you initialize the logger outside of the block. The logger object will store internally the original reference and it won't work:

```rb
logger = Logger.new($stdout)
expect { logger.info('Hello') }.to output.to_stdout # This won't work
```

As per the second question:

```rb
expect(Logger.new(STDOUT).info('Hello')).to receive(:info)
```

This is just a wrong usage of Rspec. It should be something like:

```rb
logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
expect(logger).to receive(:info)   
logger.info("Hello")
```

Answer (score 2):

I typically just use doubles like this:

```
describe 'logging' do
  it 'handles output' do
    logger = double('logger')
    allow(Logger).to receive(:new).and_return(logger)

    run_some_code
    expect(logger).to receive(:info).with("Hello")
  end
end
```

Comment: Looks like a pretty non-straightforward workaround, it's quite hard for me to understand how it works. I hope there is a better way

Comment: Well you don't need to test that the logger class is actually doing it's job, you just want to ensure you're use of the logger class is outputting your specific message.  This is the best way to do it IMO.

Comment: @Anthony, what if you subclass `Logger` and override `info`, like I did? Then you need to test it, otherwise your test coverage won't be 100%.

Comment: @WilsonSilva then you'd need unit tests for your overrides not for the `Logger` parent class.